# SQL - Find a missing entries in multiple columns in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following Oracle database concepts:

- **Account_Household** table with an identity column of **Account_Household_ID**
- **Account_Member** table with an identity column of **Account_Member_ID** and a column of  **Account_Household_ID**
- **Account_Role** table with columns of **Main_ID** and **Support_ID**, which are values representing *Account_Member_ID*
- **VIP_User** table with **VIP_ID** which is a value representing **Account_Member_ID**

I need to find those **Account_Household_IDs** where there is an associated **Account_Member_ID** that doesn't have a match in either the **Main_ID**, **Support_ID**,  or **VIP_ID** columns.   I've done searches for examples and answers, but I guess the search terms I've used to define the problem aren't good enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1350/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Account_Household (
  Account_Household_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO Account_Household
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;

CREATE TABLE Account_Member (
  Account_Member_ID    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  Account_Household_ID NUMBER,
  FOREIGN KEY ( Account_Household_ID ) REFERENCES Account_Household ( Account_Household_ID )
);

INSERT INTO Account_Member
SELECT LEVEL, 2*LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50;

CREATE TABLE Account_Role (
  Main_ID NUMBER,
  Support_ID NUMBER,
  FOREIGN KEY ( Main_ID ) REFERENCES Account_Member ( Account_Member_ID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( Support_ID ) REFERENCES Account_Member ( Account_Member_ID )
);

INSERT INTO Account_Role
SELECT LEVEL, 2*LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25;

CREATE TABLE VIP_User (
  VIP_ID NUMBER,
  FOREIGN KEY ( VIP_ID ) REFERENCES Account_Member ( Account_Member_ID )
);

INSERT INTO VIP_User
SELECT 3*LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY 3*LEVEL < 25;
```

**Query 1**:

To find the rows when a `FOREIGN KEY` is in the parent table but not the children then there are various options including using the `MINUS` operation, using a correlated sub-query and `NOT EXISTS` or using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and filtering for `NULL` entries in the child table:

```
SELECT  m.Account_Member_ID,
        m.Account_Household_ID
FROM    Account_Member m
        INNER JOIN
        Account_Household h
        ON ( m.Account_Household_ID = h.Account_Household_ID )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Account_Role r
        ON (   m.Account_Member_ID = r.Main_ID
            OR m.Account_Member_ID = r.Support_ID )
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        VIP_User v
        ON (   m.Account_Member_ID = v.VIP_ID )
WHERE   v.VIP_ID IS NULL
AND     r.Main_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY m.Account_Member_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1350/3/0)**:

```
| ACCOUNT_MEMBER_ID | ACCOUNT_HOUSEHOLD_ID |
|-------------------|----------------------|
|                27 |                   54 |
|                29 |                   58 |
|                31 |                   62 |
|                33 |                   66 |
|                35 |                   70 |
|                37 |                   74 |
|                39 |                   78 |
|                41 |                   82 |
|                43 |                   86 |
|                45 |                   90 |
|                47 |                   94 |
|                49 |                   98 |
```